# Automatically refresh page after client enable javascript

Tags: javascript, refresh, noscript

I can't find a solution, if client enables javascript on his browser, the page should automatically refresh (client doesn't have to click on refresh button)
Im using noscript 
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You mean, you want some way for the web server to refresh the page if the site visitor allows JavaScript *after* they load the page? You can't do that, because JavaScript can't be run until the page is refreshed (I'm not sure what the current default is, but NoScript at least use to automatically refresh all pages that JavaScript was just allowed on).